# Java generic understanding Type

Tags: java, generics

I am learning Java generic from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html and I have some doubts on the code sample below:

```
public class Box<T> {

    private T t;          

    public void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u) {
        System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
        integerBox.set(new Integer(10));
        integerBox.inspect("some text"); // error: this is still String!
    }
}
```

Why wasnt the inspect() method to be written as shown below instead it was ?

```
 public <T extends Number> void inspect(T t) { }
```

There are some other code samples which has the following syntax. What does the 1st pair  stands for?

```
public <K,V> SomeClass<K,V>
```

What does static  stands for?

```
public static <T> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem)
```

Comment: your example `public <K,V> SomeClass<K,V>` should be written `public class SomeClass<K,V>` :)

Comment: `Why wasnt the inspect() method to be written as shown below instead it was ?` Same as why you can't have two fields with the same name: because `T` is already used for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Box.inspect()` expects a type that extends `Number` so it is not applicable when the argument is a String.

`Box.inspect()` is just an example of generic type applied to a method.

On other hand you have a class `Box` with generic type `T`, but you can also have a method that accepts another type `U` which is broader (upper bounded) than `T`.

The class itself does not say how to use `inspect` and why, it just give you the possibility to handle different types. Don't put great expectations by this sample.

Consider that it is a just a sample that explain how to use Generics (not great logic behind).

Regarding `public class SomeClass<K,V>` declaration, this a declaration with multiple generics types.

The class [`HashMap<K,V>()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is a real sample of this case, `K` is the type for the key value and `V` is the type for the value.

Comment: yes I understand it is a String. But, why U extends Number? Can I rename it as T extends Number instead?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything yes you can.

Comment: But what does the <K,V> in front of SomeClass<K,V> stands for? since SomeClass<K,V> represents key and value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u) {
```

waits for a parameter that is of Number type or a derived of it.
So  you cannot of course pass a String value :

```
integerBox.inspect("some text"); // error: this is still String!
```

---

In your class, you declare two parameterized type :

- one in the class declaration : `public class Box<T> {`
- another in the `public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u)` method.

These set two distinct constraints.

When you declare an instance of Box with Integer as generic type:

```
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<>();
```

This following field using the T type will be associated to an Integer type :

```
private T t;
```

but the `public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u)` method doesn't use the T
type. 
So you can use distinct types in the two cases:

```
    Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
    integerBox.set(new Integer(10));
    integerBox.inspect(Float.valueOf(10)); // I pass a float and it is valid.
```

If you would declare the method in this way :

```
 public <T extends Number> void inspect(T t) { }
```

you would have the same behavior as `T` in the declared method would be another `T` type as which one declared in the class.
But this way is misleading as you use use twice the same type name (`T`) while these are distinct types.

Otherwise, to constraint the parameter of the method to the type declared in the class, you have not to declare still a type.

This is enough :

```
 public void inspect(T t) { }
```

Now you can only use the same type in the two cases:

```
    Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
    integerBox.set(new Integer(10));
    integerBox.inspect(Float.valueOf(10)); // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Freedev answer is correct. 
Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test1<Integer> integerBox = new Test1<Integer>();
    integerBox.set(new Integer(10));
    integerBox.inspect(78); //  inspect method expect a interger value
}
```